# WSO2 Api Manager: how to see the requested URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 maps the requested Url called in it to an Url in another server. How can see the mapped URL that WSO2 effectively called?

Comment: Which WSO2 product are you referring to?

Comment: @Bee it is the Api management product.  I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found an answer at WSO2 blog: [Trace API calls and responses](https://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/trace-api-calls-and-responses/}.

1. Open for editing the API that you want to trace,
2. Go to step 2 (Implement),
3. Click the Enable Message Mediation checkbox and then select the debug_ sequences from the dropdowns for all 3 flows below it
4. Click the Next: Manage button at the bottom of the screen,
5. Click Save & Publish at the bottom of the last step of the editing wizard.
6. Open the live log by clicking the Configure / Admin Dashboard menu, and then clicking Log Analyzer / Live Log Viewer in Admin Dashboard’s left-hand menu pane.
7. Now invoke the API (for example, in the API Store‘s API Console for that API).
8. You will see detailed information on the API request and response in the log
9. When you are done troubleshooting, disable the message mediation that you enabled in step 3.

This solution has a great disadvantage: you must have Analytics running (I don't have it now). But you can turn it on just for your own API. If you don't have Analytics running, you can compromise with @Bee solution below and some `tail -f|grep` .

Answer (score 2):

For debugging, another option you have is enabling wire logs.

1) Uncomment below line in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

2) Restart the Server.

3) Send a request and wire logs can be found in console and `<APIM_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log` file.

Comment: It worked but:

1) The debug log writes a lot of info. You need to grep it to make it useful.
2) You still need to configure your API. Go to API Manager → Implement → Message Mediation Policies → Out Flow and select *debug_out_flow* to have the destiny url in the log, or *log_out_message* to have just the destiny host in the log.